# 2 EL em um mesmo value

Tags: primefaces

Meu outputText está assim:

```
<p:outputLabel id="codigoGrid" value="#{bean.loja eq null ? bean.codigo : bean.codigo bean.loja}" />
```

Estou tentando fazer uma condição tenaria mas ele não aceita e a tela não é renderizada, alguém sabe se é possível fazer e como seria ?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de um operador ternário não da para colocar dois valores de bean da mesma forma que você fez. É necessário concatenar os resultados se você quiser fazê-lo, tipo assim:

```
<p:outputLabel id="codigoGrid" value="#{bean.loja eq null ? bean.codigo : bean.codigo + ' ' + bean.loja}" />
```

Obs: É preciso certificar-se que as variáveis `bean.codigo` e `bean.loja` sejam de fato Strings, caso contrário ocorrerá um erro de cast.